# Combining arrays based on proximity using scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

My goal here is to combine arrays that have elements that are less than 3 pixels away from all of the other arrays. Here is the code that I am using:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
from scipy.ndimage import label 

## Example matrix
arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
                [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

## Check if neighboring cells are zero using a 2d convolution:
# The kernel
ker = np.array([[1,1,1],
                [1,0,1],
                [1,1,1]])
ker2= np.array([[1,1,1],
                [1,1,1],
                [1,1,1]])
res = convolve2d(arr,ker,mode='same')

# Eliminate the noise
res = np.int32((res>0)&(arr>0))

# Using label your can segment an image and since an image is basically a matrix:
lab = label(res, ker2)
print(lab)
# Get the coordinate of each line.
coord = []
for ii in range(lab[1]):
    coord.append(np.vstack(np.where(lab[0]==(ii+1))))




for i, e in enumerate(coord):
    xVals = e[1]
    yVals = e[0]
    plt.scatter(xVals, yVals)

plt.xlim(0,len(arr[0]))
plt.ylim(0,len(arr))
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0,len(arr), len(arr)+1))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This returns:

[image: Figure]

Notice how the blue, green, and orange data points (pixels) are separate arrays. I want to combine the blue and green arrays (1 pixel apart) while leaving the orange array (>2 pixels apart. The array here assigned to the variable 'arr' is just sample data. The real data will come from a large image file so the solution to this problem must be efficient enough to be practical on a larger scale.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use a larger ker2, to run label()

Comment: @Colim I tried that but I get this error message: "ValueError: structure dimensions must be equal to 3". Apparently it needs to be three by three :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use your algorithm with a little change:

First grow each pixel one pixel:

```
(n,m) = arr.shape
arr_out =  np.zeros((n+2,m+2))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if arr[i,j] == 1:
            for k in range(3):
                for l in range(3):
                    arr_out[i+k][j+l] = 1
arr_out = arr_out[1:-1,1:-1]
```

Next run your algorithm with the new image: arr_out

You can then use arr as a mask on lab:

```
lab[0][arr<1] = 0
```

Giving:
[image]

Alternatively to writing your own loop you can use to following routine from skimage :

```
from skimage.morphology import square, dilation
dilation(arr, square(3))
```